# Trouble installing/compiling lua on macosx

Tags: macos, lua

I have been attempting to compile/install Lua on Snow Leopard. I have changed the target platform in the Makefile.std to macosx and I still get the following issue:

```
sudo make -f Makefile.std macosx

make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'macosx'. Stop
make: *** [macsox] Error 2
```

I also changed the target of the same Makefile.std file in the src directory.

Is there something I'm missing here?

I have tried "make macosx" amongst other variations...

This should be easy.

Answer (score 4):

Did you download the source from lua.org? The official distribution does not contain a Makefile.std. Doing "make macosx" should just work. Get the [official tarball](http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.4.tar.gz).

Comment: Same "geo" as above (login troubles). LHF, thank you. You are my hero today. I thought I downloaded the tarball from Lua.org, odd. Guess not... The tarball was " lua5_1_4_Sources.tar.gz" All is compiled and good now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that there are Lua packages in [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/).